# JavaFX - How to select one shape to do animation?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, shapes

I have the following circle and I can play animation on it:

[image]

Suppose I want to add another shape, such as a rectangle. How I can select between the shapes (circle/rectangle) through a mouse-click to do the animation on the shape being selected. Could someone please give me some guidelines/examples as to how I would go about this. Thank you!

Program Code:

```
import javafx.animation.PathTransition; 
import javafx.application.Application; 
import static javafx.application.Application.launch; 
import javafx.event.EventHandler; 

import javafx.scene.Group; 
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.control.Button; 
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent; 
import javafx.scene.paint.Color; 

import javafx.scene.shape.Circle; 
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo; 
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo; 
import javafx.scene.shape.Path; 
import javafx.stage.Stage; 
import javafx.util.Duration; 

public class ConvinienceMethodsExample extends Application { 
   @Override 
   public void start(Stage stage) {      
      //Drawing a Circle 
      Circle circle = new Circle(); 

      //Setting the position of the circle 
      circle.setCenterX(300.0f); 
      circle.setCenterY(135.0f); 

      //Setting the radius of the circle 
      circle.setRadius(25.0f);  

      //Setting the color of the circle 
      circle.setFill(Color.BROWN); 

      //Setting the stroke width of the circle 
      circle.setStrokeWidth(20);      

      //Creating a Path 
      Path path = new Path(); 

      //Moving to the staring point 
      MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(208, 71);               

      //Creating 1st line 
      LineTo line1 = new LineTo(421, 161);        

      //Creating 2nd line 
      LineTo line2 = new LineTo(226,232); 

      //Creating 3rd line 
      LineTo line3 = new LineTo(332,52);        

      //Creating 4th line 
      LineTo line4 = new LineTo(369, 250);        

      //Creating 5th line 
      LineTo line5 = new LineTo(208, 71);       

      //Adding all the elements to the path 
      path.getElements().add(moveTo); 
      path.getElements().addAll(line1, line2, line3, line4, line5);     

      //Creating the path transition 
      PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition(); 

      //Setting the duration of the transition 
      pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));       

      //Setting the node for the transition 
      pathTransition.setNode(circle); 

      //Setting the path for the transition 
      pathTransition.setPath(path); 

      //Setting the orientation of the path 
      pathTransition.setOrientation(
         PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TAN GENT);

      //Setting the cycle count for the transition 
      pathTransition.setCycleCount(50); 

      //Setting auto reverse value to true 
      pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);

      //Creating play button 
      Button playButton = new Button("Play"); 
      playButton.setLayoutX(300); 
      playButton.setLayoutY(250); 

      circle.setOnMouseClicked (new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() { 
         @Override 
         public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent e) { 
            System.out.println("Hello World"); 
            circle.setFill(Color.DARKSLATEBLUE);             
         } 
      });   
      playButton.setOnMouseClicked((new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
         public void handle(MouseEvent event) { 
            System.out.println("Hello World");  
            pathTransition.play(); 
         } 
      })); 

      //Creating stop button 
      Button stopButton = new Button("stop"); 
      stopButton.setLayoutX(250); 
      stopButton.setLayoutY(250); 

      stopButton.setOnMouseClicked((new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
         public void handle(MouseEvent event) { 
            System.out.println("Hello World"); 
            pathTransition.stop(); 
         } 
      }));
      //Creating a Group object  
      Group root = new Group(circle, playButton, stopButton); 

      //Creating a scene object 
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300); 
      scene.setFill(Color.LAVENDER);  

      //Setting title to the Stage 
      stage.setTitle("Convenience Methods Example");  

      //Adding scene to the stage 
      stage.setScene(scene); 

      //Displaying the contents of the stage 
      stage.show(); 
   } 
   public static void main(String args[]){ 
      launch(args); 
   } 
}
```

Code to add a Rectangle shape:

```
  //Drawing a Rectangle
  Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 75); 

  //Setting the color of the rectangle 
  rectangle.setFill(Color.BURLYWOOD); 

  //Setting the stroke color of the rectangle 
  rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: One thing you can do is when you click on a shape, move it `toFront()`. Then always play the animation on the shape that is in the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouse listener on the shape to select the animated one:

```
public class ConvinienceMethodsExample extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) {

      Circle circle = new Circle(300,135,25,Color.BROWN);
      circle.setStrokeWidth(20);

      Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 75);
      rectangle.setFill(Color.BURLYWOOD);

      Path path = new Path();
      MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(208, 71);
      LineTo line1 = new LineTo(421, 161);
      LineTo line2 = new LineTo(226,232);
      LineTo line3 = new LineTo(332,52);
      LineTo line4 = new LineTo(369, 250);
      LineTo line5 = new LineTo(208, 71);
      path.getElements().add(moveTo);
      path.getElements().addAll(line1, line2, line3, line4, line5);

      PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(1000), path, circle);
      pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
      pathTransition.setCycleCount(50);
      pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);

      //Creating play button
      Button playButton = new Button("Play");
      playButton.setLayoutX(300);//do not set bounds. Use layouts:
      playButton.setLayoutY(250);//https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm

      playButton.setOnAction(event -> {//no need to setOnMouseClicked on a buton
        pathTransition.stop();
        pathTransition.play();
     });

      Button stopButton = new Button("stop");
      stopButton.setLayoutX(250);
      stopButton.setLayoutY(250);
      stopButton.setOnAction(event -> pathTransition.stop());

      circle.setOnMouseClicked (e -> {
         pathTransition.setNode(circle); //apply transition to circle
        circle.setFill(Color.DARKSLATEBLUE);
     });

      rectangle.setOnMouseClicked (e -> {
         pathTransition.setNode(rectangle); //apply transition to rectangle
     });

      Group root = new Group(circle, rectangle, playButton, stopButton);
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);
      scene.setFill(Color.LAVENDER);

      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
      launch(args);
   }
}
```