# Drag-to-draw line Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, line, scene

I'm want to be able to drag-to-draw a line that ends in the center of each of two nodes (circles). I have two event handlers that I'm thinking listen for new mouse clicks, but whenever I click, nothing happens.

Here is the Start method:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;




@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500,500);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        //Draw Circles onto a Pane:
        Pane overlay = new Pane();
        for (int i = 50; i < xDim; i+=50) {
            for (int j = 50; j < yDim; j+=50) {
                Circle c1 = new Circle();
                c1.setCenterX(i);
                c1.setCenterY(j);
                c1.setRadius(5);
                overlay.getChildren().add(c1);
            }
        }


        drawLine(overlay);
        root.getChildren().addAll(canvas,overlay);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

And here is drawLine():

```
            Line l = new Line();
            overlay.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {


                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    if (t.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                        Circle p = ((Circle) (t.getSource()));

                        double circleX = p.getCenterX();
                        double circleY = p.getCenterY();

                        l.setStartX(circleX);
                        l.setStartY(circleY);


                    } else {
                        Node p = ((Node) (t.getSource()));

                        double orgTranslateX = p.getTranslateX();
                        double orgTranslateY = p.getTranslateY();
                    }
                }
            });

            overlay.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {


                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    if (t.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                        Circle p = ((Circle) (t.getSource()));

                        double circleX = p.getCenterX();
                        double circleY = p.getCenterY();

                        l.setEndX(circleX);
                        l.setEndY(circleY);
                        overlay.getChildren().add(l);
                    } else{}
                }
            });
        };
```

You can see draw line has two different event handlers, one for a click and one for release, and the only thing that changes is myLine.setEndX().

Any help would be appreciated! I apologize in advance for any unknown transgressions.

Comment: The source of an event is the node with which it was registered (ie the `overlay` pane), so the condition in the `if` statement is always false. Why not register handlers with the circles instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response! So as I have it now, I have registered handlers with drawLine()? And I should create event handlers in my Start method? Should I make each circle a node?

Just trying to keep up. Thanks again!

Comment: Register an mouse event handle on each circle. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500193/3992939). When clicked keep the circle center. When released keep the other center.